# Failed Push Notificatblanion Firebase - empty error message

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I receive a blank error message for Pushnotification - firebase

All notification are working except push notfication. Is there any specific setup we need to enable in Firebase.

I placed below most of the flutter setup that provides the pushnotication.

```
class PushNotificationsBloc
    extends Bloc<PushNotificationsEvent, PushNotificationsState> {
  final UserDataRepository userDataRepository;

  PushNotificationsBloc({this.userDataRepository})
      : super(PushNotificationsInitial());

  @override
  Stream<PushNotificationsState> mapEventToState(
    PushNotificationsEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SendNewNotification) {
      yield* mapSendNewNotificationToState(event.map);
    }
  }

  Stream<PushNotificationsState> mapSendNewNotificationToState(Map map) async* {
    yield SendNewNotificationInProgressState();
    try {
      String res = await userDataRepository.sendNewNotification(map);
      if (res != null) {
        yield SendNewNotificationCompletedState(res);
      } else {
        yield SendNewNotificationFailedState();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      yield SendNewNotificationFailedState();
    }
  }
}
```

```
@immutable
abstract class PushNotificationsState {}

class PushNotificationsInitial extends PushNotificationsState {}

class SendNewNotificationCompletedState extends PushNotificationsState {
  final String res;

  SendNewNotificationCompletedState(this.res);
}

class SendNewNotificationFailedState extends PushNotificationsState {}

class SendNewNotificationInProgressState extends PushNotificationsState {}
```

Comment: `I receive a blank error message for Pushnotification`, can you please share a picture of this?

Comment: Which version of firebase_messaging are you usind?

Comment: flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+4 firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0

Comment: I/flutter ( 3096): FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 3096):
I/flutter ( 3096): ^